# Divide two nodes (inputs)

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have two nodes:

```
BatteryAmps 
BatteryAmps : msg.payload : number
-7.699999809265137

Watts
Watts : msg.payload : number
358
```

I take BatteryAmps and multiply it by 1000 to give me how many usable watts there are left.

```
BatteryAmps : msg.payload : number
7700
```

I then want to divide new `BatteryAmps : msg.payload` by `Watts : msg.payload : number`

In the above example I would expect to see 21.5 (this would be hours to go).

I've watched so many videos and read about adding values I inject together or other calculations but cannot find any help on how to deal with two inputs that are coming automatically.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check out [ask] and include the relevant code in a [mre]

Comment: The join node is your friend (p.s. add distinct `msg.topic` values to the output of the 2 input nodes...)

Comment: Check https://cookbook.nodered.org/basic/join-streams